# Angularjs Unknown service provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I have a service created this way:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
module.exports = siteAuthService;

angular
    .module('authSite', [])
    .factory('siteAuthService', ['$q', '$http', 'Requester', 'tsModulesService', siteAuthService]);


function siteAuthService($q, $http, Requester, tsModulesService) {

    var factoryDefinitionObject = {
        getUserByEmail: getUser,
        createUser: createSiteUser,
        recoverPassword: recoverPassword
    };


    return factoryDefinitionObject;

   ...


 }  
})();
```

And a controller where I am trying to inject this service:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('formOrderDialog')
    .controller('FormOrderDialogController', FormOrderDialogController)
    .filter('getById', getById)
;

FormOrderDialogController.$inject = ['tsModulesService', '$scope', '$q', '$http', '$uibModalInstance', 'params', '$filter', 'Requester', 'dateHelpers', '$translate', 'alertService', '$uibModal',
    'SaleLineFactory', 'tsPrintSelectService', 'tsPrintService', 'EntrySectorService', 'uiGridConstants', 'confirmationDialogService', 'siteAuthService'];

function FormOrderDialogController(tsModulesService, $scope, $q, $http, $uibModalInstance, params, $filter, Requester, dateHelpers, $translate, alertService, $uibModal,
                                   SaleLineFactory, tsPrintSelectService, tsPrintService, entrySectorService, uiGridConstants, confirmationDialogService, siteAuthService) {
       ...
       ...
   }
})();
```

And module:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

const module = angular
    .module('formOrderDialog', [])
 ;

 })();
```

But I am getting an `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: siteAuthServiceProvider <- siteAuthService <- FormOrderDialogController`

I also tried to `require("../../services/siteAuthService");` 
it in formOrderDialog module, but still can't inject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service is declared in the `'authSite'` module, while the controller is declared in the `'formOrderDialog'` module.  You need to inject the `authSite` module in order to access the service from it.

```
const module = angular
    .module('formOrderDialog', ['authSite']);
```

Comment: plus one Nicely detected